# P = NP, NP example problems in our daily life

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, examples-counterexamples

For a little presentation for school, i want to try to explain the P=NP? Problem.
I'm searching for examples for daily life NP-problems. (example: is making the weather forecast a NP problem?)

And if P=NP, wat would change in our daily life? Encryption depends on the fact that it is a NP-problem, so you could solve it quickly if P=NP. I've heard that, if P=NP we could treat cancer in a different way?

I Know some examples, but explaining complex math problems as an example is not good in this situation.

Comment: Have you had a look at [the Wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P_versus_NP_problem#Consequences_of_solution) already, and at [The Status of the P Versus NP Problem](http://cacm.acm.org/magazines/2009/9/38904-the-status-of-the-p-versus-np-problem/fulltext#body-3)?

Comment: http://www.claymath.org/millenium-problems/p-vs-np-problem and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem would be a couple of links I'd suggest.

Comment: The cancer connection sounded fishy, but [apparently](http://www.scottaaronson.com/blog/?p=1293) it's discussed in [this book](http://www.amazon.com/The-Golden-Ticket-Search-Impossible/dp/0691156492/). Sounds like it may be just the reference you're looking for.

Comment: [This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=msp2y_Y5MLE&list=LLu4cTb4tYV1xMNyUp_8PklQ&index=31) is perhaps the *best* down-to-earth explanations of P vs. NP I know of that should fit to your need! Also cryptography and credit cards are good examples to have in mind.

Comment: More accurately, if $P=NP$ tractably, and if there is a cure for cancer, then we will find it by putting everything humanity knows about the universe into computers and running the NP solver.  The most important problem that $P=NP$ solves is "Is there a proof of length $n$ of problem $p$", whose importance cannot be overstated.  It would end the profession of mathematician and turn engineers into formula translators.

Answer (score 0):

My favourite example is [Sudoku](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sudoku), a game nowadays known by almost everyone. Just explain that it is easy to *check* whether a solution is correct (class NP) while it looks be much harder to *find* a solution (so most Sudoku's players will hardly believe that the problem is in P...)